# ParameterNotFoundException on symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I've this error when I run the website,

**`ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "ppr.database.host.dev".`**

I put the var in my terminal env, env returns me :

```
SYMFONY__PPR__DATABASE__HOST__DEV=localhost
```

I also put the var in my 2 php.ini files, 
export

`SetEnv SYMFONY__PPR__DATABASE__HOST__DEV localhost`

And this var appears also in app/config/parameters.ini,

```
database_host = %ppr.database.host.dev%
```

Comment: why don't you want to put 'ppr.database.host.dev' directly in parameters.ini? 
another question: why don't you use 'yml' parameters instead of 'ini'?

Comment: Because I take part to the development of a project so I can modify the code like I want to.
config.yml makes the import of parameters.ini like in symfony2 tutorial (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html Miscellaneous Configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for parameters.ini just simple add:

```ini
[parameters]
    ppr.database.host.dev = "localhost"
    database_host = %ppr.database.host.dev%
```

another way to have this parameter available for website: you should set evn in your host configuration.
for arapache it should be something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    SetEnv          SYMFONY__PPR__DATABASE__HOST__DEV localhost
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Here is my code in my apache2/php.ini file and cli/php.ini file.
`SetEnv SYMFONY__PPR__DATABASE__HOST__DEV localhost`
I put this code a the end of the file

Comment: `SetEnv SYMFONY__PPR__DATABASE__HOST__DEV localhost` - this code should be in your apache virtual host configuration, not in php.ini.
try to put it there.